# Prefixing an output file in bash with brace expansion after sox processing

Tags: linux, bash, sox, brace-expansion

Given several subdirectories of mixed files on a Ubuntu 16.04 server, I want to take all the ones named like `1.al`, `2.al` etc, process them, keep the original files, and prefix the resulting files with `quick_`. So I have this...

```
find . -name '[[:digit:]]*.al' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 'for f; do sox  -c1 --rate 8k "$f" -e a-law "quick_${f}" tempo -q -s 1.5; done' sh {}
```

But I get

```
can't open output file `quick_./1.al': No such file or directory
```

I can see why it is happening, and I have the feeling that the answer lies in brace expansion. I've found recipes for stripping and adding suffixes, but the prefix answer is eluding me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a lot to go on here, but I think you want to use the `basename` command to get just the filename:

```
find . -name '[[:digit:]]*.al' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 'for f; do sox  -c1 --rate 8k "$f" -e a-law "$(dirname "$f")/quick_$(basename "$f")" tempo -q -s 1.5; done' sh {}
```

Personally, I find it a bit easier working with the `-exec` flag to `find`. It's one less level of indirection to worry about. `{}` represents the filename, and the command is terminated with a `;` (escaped so the shell doesn't grab it.)

```
find . -name '[[:digit:]]*.al' -exec sh -c 'sox -c1 --rate 8k "{}" -e a-law "$(dirname "{}")/quick_$(basename "{}")" tempo -q -s 1.5' \;
```

Comment: Thanks! It didn't quite work as expected as it dumps all the resulting files into the directory from which run, so I just changed it to `$(dirname {})/quick_$(basename {})`
If it's OK, what I'll do is give you a point, type my alternative up as an answer, referring to yours. If that's OK by SO etiquette!

Comment: I've updated the answer to include that. Typically you wouldn't write your own answer unless you came up with a different solution.

Comment: Thanks - duly selected and given the tick!